# Resource.designer.cs won't update

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

This seems to be a chronic issue with Xamarin Studio, and like many others I can't get my Resource.designer.cs file to update as I edit my layout files. I renamed some of my layout files, however Resource.designer.cs still has the old names so the app no longer builds and I'm completely blocked. I'm using the latest stable versions of Mono / Xamarin.Android / Androik SDK components: https://gist.github.com/justintoth/335cbd76cabf87385a4b11c8501c5ce8

I've read all of the other SO / Xamarin threads, and have tried:

- Changing the id of an existing layout element to trigger a refresh
- Clean / rebuild
- Deleting bin / obj folders
- Erasing the contents of Resource.designer.cs then rebuilding (it remains empty)
- Deleting Resource.designer.cs, rebuilding, then re-adding it to the project (the freshly generated file is completely empty)
- Double-checking that I don't have any resource files in my project with bad symbols, e.g. dashes
- Ensuring I have the necessary elements in the first PropertyGroup of the project file: https://gist.github.com/justintoth/c4e9b212754824587da465495f92555c

At this point, I'm completely blocked and have no other things to try. I could really use some help...

Comment: If your resource designer file is not updating and assuming you did not manually remove the `AndroidResgenFile` property from the `.csproj`, then you have invalid content within your `Resources`. Perform a build and look at your `APTxxxx` error(s).

Comment: Your best friend here is a diagnostic build output. As mentioned by SushiHangover, you'll want to be looking at the errors spit out by `aapt`. These should be very obvious when rebuilding your project. Please upload a diagnostic build output to this question.

Comment: Wow, thanks! You're right, there were a couple issues: Resources/layout/AccountChangePassword.axml(2): error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_below' with value '@id/login_logo_divider').
  Resources/layout/AccountForgotPassword.axml(2): error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_below' with value '@id/login_logo_divider'). The strange thing is that these layouts haven't been changed in a while, it's as if an Android update triggered it to start erroring when these elements weren't found, whereas before it let it go.

Comment: @JonDouglas - I spoke too soon about it updating correctly... I added some more new elements today to a layout and it again isn't updating, even though I don't see layout issues in the logs: https://gist.github.com/justintoth/407ffea85b0ebd0bdbe6984b67724504

Comment: In this case I had another layout issue, but it didn't show in the aapt logs. Is there any way we can get these layout errors showing in Xamarin Studio instead of having to get confused when Resource.designer.cs doesn't update and then having to comb through the logs? It just doesn't seem like the most productive way to handle layout errors for developers...

Comment: @Justin Please file a bug here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Android regarding this issue.